# If $|xH|$ has order $n$, then there is an element $y$ with $|y|=n$ and $xH=yH$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and let $H$ be a normal subgroup with $|H|=m$. Suppose $n$ and $m$ are relatively prime. If $|xH|$ has order $n$, we wish to find an element $y$ with $|y|=n$ and $xH=yH$.

It is easy to see that $|xH|=n$ divides $|x|$, say $|x|=nt$. (We note also that $x^{n} \in H$.) Of course, we now have that $|x^{t}|=n$, one of our desired conditions. But, I don't see that $xH=x^{t}H$. So maybe this isn't our $y$.

Well, we know also that there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $1=ma+nb$. Now, the element $x^{ma}$ has the property that $xH=x^{ma}H$, but I don't see how to say much more about its order.

Answer (score 1):

The preimage of $\langle xH\rangle$ under the natural projection $G\rightarrow \frac{G}{H}$ is a group with $mn$ elements. It contains $\langle x \rangle$ which implies $x$ has order $nd$ with $d|m$ and since $(n,m)=1$ we have $(d,n)=1$. Consider the powers of $x$:

$x,x^2\dots x^n,x^{n+1}\dots x^{nd}=e$. The elements that are in $xH$ are those which have exponent congruent to $1\bmod n$. On the other hand the elements that have order $n$ are those in which the exponent is $dj$ with $(j,n)=1$.

So the element of $xH$ of order $n$ will be $x^{dj}$ so that $dj\equiv 1 \bmod n$, this is clearly possible, just take $j\equiv d^{-1}\bmod n$. The inverse exists since $(d,n)=1$.